# How to change color of the Text caret in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have loaded the extension  [Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor) and want to change the color of the blinking text caret. Where can I find this setting or what is this called in the color theme editor?

Comment: Not the mouse cursor. its the Text caret i want to change. aka:  ‘text cursor’, ‘text insertion cursor’, or ‘text selection cursor’